# Custom Maven clean with fileset not working

Tags: maven, fileset

I have created an additional target directory called "dist" to which I am copying some build artifacts.  Because it is not in the default target directories, I add an appropriate  to the clean plugin configuration per [Delete Additional Files](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html) instructions for the plugin, as follows:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <fileset>
                    <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    <directory>dist</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileset>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But the "dist" directory and its contents remains after any "mvn clean".  I've tried a number of variants, and checked the output of "mvn help:effective-pom" or the "mvn -X" debug output and, I find:

1. The configuration is showing up in submodules' effective pom's.
2. There is no error message
3. There is **no** sign of "dist" directories or their contents in the debug output.
4. Explicit references like `<directory>${basedir}/dist</directory>` make no difference.
5. Likewise, using more or less explicit `<include>` references like "*.jar" or "**/*.txt" make no difference.

I'm using maven 3.0.3, clean plugin 2.5.  I tried 2.4, just in case. No difference.  Also, no permission problems.

I've scanned dozens of examples in Google, and all merely repeat the documentation's instructions.  I am relatively new to Maven and still learning.  Am I blind to something obvious?  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need such a dist folder? Why not using target/dist ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `<fileset>` tag within the `<filesets>` tag

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>dist</directory>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost,

Here's a working one:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<configuration>
    <filesets>
        <fileset>
            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>dist/**</include> 
                <include>target</include> 
            </includes>
        </fileset>
    </filesets>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use instead of:

```
                  <includes>
                        <include>*</include>
                  </includes>
```

Something like

```
                   <includes>
                        <include>**/*.*</include>
                   </includes>
```

It worked for me using Maven 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <fileset>
                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                <directory>${basedir}</directory> <!-- Careful with this -->
                <includes>
                    <include>dist</include> 
                    <include>target</include> 
                </includes>
            </fileset>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```